# mySql combine two SELECT queries with JOIN

Tags: php, mysql

I have two mySql queries to get result from databases. I am trying to join them together.

Query 1:

```
SELECT userEwallets.id as ewalletId, users.id as userId , money_repositories.money as money, a.nestedUserId
FROM userEwallets
JOIN users ON users.id = userEwallets.userId
JOIN money_repositories ON userEwallets.id = money_repositories.ewalletId
WHERE ewalletNumber = 'SHIRR937303656'
```

Query 2:

```
SELECT nested.id as nestedUserId
FROM userEwallets as nested
JOIN users ON users.id = nested.userId
JOIN money_repositories ON nested.id = money_repositories.ewalletId
WHERE ewalletNumber = 'SHIRR9122331743'
```

and then my combination command:

```
SELECT userEwallets.id as ewalletId, users.id as userId , money_repositories.money as money, a.nestedUserId
FROM (
    SELECT nested.id as nestedUserId
    FROM userEwallets as nested
    JOIN users ON users.id = nested.userId
    JOIN money_repositories ON nested.id = money_repositories.ewalletId
    WHERE ewalletNumber = 'SHIRR912233'
)    as a
JOIN users ON users.id = userEwallets.userId
JOIN money_repositories ON userEwallets.id = money_repositories.ewalletId
WHERE ewalletNumber = 'SHIRR93730'
```

I get this error:

```
#1054 - Unknown column 'userEwallets.id' in 'field list'
```

Both of commands are same but they have simple difference as `ewalletNumber` in `where` clause

**UPDATE WITH DATABASE STRUCTURE**

`money_repositories` table:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `money_repositories` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `userId` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `ewalletId` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `money` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `createdAt` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `updatedAt` int(11) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_persian_ci AUTO_INCREMENT=4 ;
```

`userEwallets` table:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `userEwallets` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `userId` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `ewalletNumber` varchar(15) COLLATE utf8_persian_ci NOT NULL,
  `currencySymbol` varchar(5) COLLATE utf8_persian_ci NOT NULL,
  `createdAt` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  `updatedAt` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT '0000-00-00 00:00:00',
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_persian_ci AUTO_INCREMENT=7 ;
```

`users` table:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `users` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `username` varchar(20) COLLATE utf8_persian_ci NOT NULL,
  `password` varchar(65) COLLATE utf8_persian_ci NOT NULL,
  `name` varchar(20) COLLATE utf8_persian_ci NOT NULL,
  `family` varchar(20) COLLATE utf8_persian_ci NOT NULL,
  `birthDay` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT '0000-00-00 00:00:00' ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  `email` varchar(20) COLLATE utf8_persian_ci NOT NULL,
  `mobileNumber` varchar(15) COLLATE utf8_persian_ci NOT NULL,
  `verifyCode` varchar(5) COLLATE utf8_persian_ci NOT NULL,
  `photoUri` varchar(50) COLLATE utf8_persian_ci NOT NULL,
  `ebanNumber` varchar(20) COLLATE utf8_persian_ci NOT NULL,
  `status` tinyint(1) NOT NULL,
  `createdAt` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT '0000-00-00 00:00:00',
  `updatedAt` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT '0000-00-00 00:00:00',
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_persian_ci AUTO_INCREMENT=35 ;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`userEwallets.id` should be `a.id` in Select of your combination command. Because you are getting subquery as `a`.

Modified combined query;

```
SELECT a.id                     AS ewalletId, 
       users.id                 AS userId, 
       money_repositories.money AS money, 
       a.nesteduserid 
FROM   (SELECT nested.id AS nestedUserId, 
               nested.id, 
               nested.ewalletnumber 
        FROM   userewallets AS nested 
               JOIN users 
                 ON users.id = nested.userid 
               JOIN money_repositories 
                 ON nested.id = money_repositories.ewalletid 
        WHERE  nested.ewalletnumber = 'SHIRR912233') AS a 
       JOIN users 
         ON users.id = userewallets.userid 
       JOIN money_repositories 
         ON userewallets.id = money_repositories.ewalletid 
WHERE  a.ewalletnumber = 'SHIRR93730'
```

camleCase query fixed:

```
SELECT a.id                     AS ewalletId, 
       users.id                 AS userId, 
       money_repositories.money AS money, 
       a.nestedUserId 
FROM   (SELECT nested.id AS nestedUserId, 
               nested.id, 
               nested.ewalletNumber 
        FROM   userEwallets AS nested 
               JOIN users                         ON users.id   = nested.userId 
               JOIN money_repositories  ON nested.id = money_repositories.ewalletId 
        WHERE  nested.ewalletNumber = 'SHIRR912233') AS a 

       JOIN users                         ON users.id            = nested.userId 
       JOIN money_repositories  ON userEwallets.id = money_repositories.ewalletId 

WHERE  a.ewalletNumber = 'SHIRR937303'
```

Comment: i get this error:  ` Unknown column 'ewalletNumber' in 'where clause'`

Comment: ewalletNumber column belongs to which table? if it belongs to `userEwallets`, try `nested.ewalletNumber = 'SHIRR912233'` you are using alias for tables while getting. But you are not using aliases on where or select situations.

Comment: i get error again #1054 - Unknown column 'nested.ewalletNumber' in 'where clause'`

Comment: You should put your tables info on your post. We dont know your database structure. You know it. Check code, I've commented inside.

Comment: Your camleCase query is not correct, i fixed that but i get error again

Comment: error: `#1054 - Unknown column 'nested.userId' in 'on clause`

Answer (score 0):

Because you are not including table `userEwallets` in the query except in the sub query which won't be recognized outside the subquery. Try

**UPDATE**

```
Select 
     users.id as userId, userEwallets.id As ewalletId,money_repositories.money
From
    users
Inner Join 
    userEwallets ON userEwallets.userId= users.id
Inner Join 
    money_repositories ON money_repositories.userId=users.id
And
    money_repositories.ewalletId = userEwallets.id
Where
    userEwallets.ewalletNumber = 'SHIRR93730'
```

Comment: Thanks, i get the same error ` Unknown column 'userEwallets.id' in 'field list'`

Comment: Yes. It should be **users.id** not **users.userId** in the outer select statement

Comment: after change `userId` to `id` i get this error: `#1054 - Unknown column 'ewalletNumber' in 'where clause`

Comment: that's why I put a comment to put the corresponding table name before `ewalletNumber`

Comment: your means is `userEwallets.ewalletNumber` on where clause? i get error again

Comment: if it's from userEwallets table then you can ignote the where statement coz it's already used in sub query.

Comment: i updated your post with correct query, please let me to test more that again